# Html layout - first element in code, but last on a page

Tags: html, css, layout

I have the next html code ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CyRYD/)):

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="first-block">
        Mauris at tortor vel nulla rutrum porta. Etiam non ...
    </div>
    <div class="second-block">
        Suspendisse suscipit tortor eu nulla interdum ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible with CSS to make `first-block` appear on a page after `second-block`? Only visually, while html layout stays the same. It's some kind of SEO.

Comment: So you want the code to stay the same but the visual html to basically swap around?

Comment: [Like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/CyRYD/4/)

Comment: @chriz, pretty much, but no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible if you use position absolute. But you must have predefined heights in order to not break your layout

```
.content {
    width: 400px;
    height:200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position:relative;
}

.first-block {
    background: coral;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}

.second-block {
    background: #DEDEDE;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
}
```

Here is [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CyRYD/1/)

Comment: But how about dynamic height? My `first-block` and `second-block` height may vary

Comment: I'm affraid this can't be done unless you're using javascript

Comment: looks like now it is achievable with Flexbox

Answer (score 1):

This is possible by using `float` and the `margin` properties.

I simply floated your two `divs` to either side, and of course `clear:both` in the middle to stop them overlapping. Once done, I used `margin-top` with both positive and negative values to position the `divs` as if the first is below the second, when in fact the first is above the second in the code.

**CSS**

```
.content {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.first-block {
    background: coral;
    margin-top:300px;
    float:left;
}

.second-block {
    background: #DEDEDE;
    margin-top:-300px;
    float:right;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="first-block">
        Mauris at tortor vel nulla rutrum porta. Etiam non condimentum velit. Phasellus turpis magna, sagittis at porta et, tincidunt id magna. Maecenas hendrerit suscipit massa, at consectetur magna tempor et. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Etiam accumsan.
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    <div class="second-block">
        Suspendisse suscipit tortor eu nulla interdum sit amet ultricies ante imperdiet. Donec varius adipiscing lectus in suscipit. Nunc risus arcu, luctus nec tempor porttitor, sodales eget lectus. Vestibulum imperdiet massa in ligula pellentesque eget egestas dui facilisis. Nunc commodo lacus at nibh tristique sodales
    </div>
</div>
```

**[Heres a fiddle demo for you!](http://jsfiddle.net/CyRYD/4/)**

Comment: As I commented to previous answer, my blocks heights may vary, so I can not just set margins in CSS. To make my blocks fit clear I have to calculate heights with javascript. Anyway, +1 for another approach